# Duct Tape a Regex Decider

Tags: code-challenge, decision-problem, parsing, regular-expression, duct-tape-coding

Your task is to create a program that determines whether a given string is a valid regular expression or not using code snippets sourced from sites on the StackExchange network.

For the purposes of this challenge, the regular expression dialect will be a stripped down and mostly minimal set of meta-characters: `()*?|\`. As such, you will not be able to use built-in regex parsers.

- `\` is used to escape meta-characters. It must be followed by a meta-character.
- Unescaped parentheses must be balanced
- `*` and `?` must be preceded by either a non-meta-character, a parenthesized group, or an escaped meta-character.
- All other printable ASCII characters plus newline, tab, and space must be supported as non-meta characters. What happens with a string containing other characters is undefined.
- The actual meaning of the regex is not important for this challenge.

### Examples

```
Truthy:
  abc
  a?
  (a|)*
  ()
  a|b*
  \*
  \\
  \\*
  a*b?(cd|e)
  +
  [
  }
  (123\))*
  \|
  (a(b(c|d)*e)*f)*
  (|\)*)
  (abc)+*
  (abc)+
  +abc

^ last test case is an actual newline

Falsy:
  ?abc
  *
  **
  \
  (
  a*?
  a?*
  ?
  a)
  (\)
  (|\)*
  \()
  |*
  (?:abc)
  \\**
  \n
```

### Scoring

Your overall score is the number of snippets taken from questions and answers around StackExchange.

- Repeated snippets count for as many times as they are used.
- Whitespace can be added and removed freely (because of Python, Haskell, and other whitespace-sensitive languages) and does not count toward your snippet count.

  - The exception would be if your code is actually written in [Whitespace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)).
- Snippets are allowed from any StackExchange site as long as they come from questions, answers, and comments that are older (Including by edit time - use older revisions if necessary) than this challenge. (Sep 24, 2019 @ 3:30 PM UTC)
- Snippets can come from anywhere in a question, answer, or comment body, whether it's in a preformatted code block or not.
- Splicing a snippet into the middle of another causes the outer snippet to count as *two* snippets

Lowest score wins!

Comment: @RobinRyder yes, changed

Comment: Can the post be older than or equal to this challenge, i.e. can we use snippets from the body of this challenge?

Comment: "As such, you will not be able to use built-in regex parsers" Is that to say that its designed to thwart using that for a simple ya/nay, or that we are forbidden from using regex at all in our answers?

Comment: @guifa it's designed so that you can't just take your language's regex engine and see if it compiles the given regex. Every language I know of supports a larger set of meta-characters and specialized capture groups, so they wouldn't match this set of characters correctly in all cases.

Comment: @JoKing, I'm going to say no on that.

Comment: Does it have to be more than one snippet? Is the program allowed to have output?

Comment: What if we cut out a part from the middle?

Comment: @JL2210 That would make it two snippets: one for the beginning and one for the end. You can use a single snippet as long as it passes all the test cases and  comes from an answer/question/post that's older than this challenge

Comment: Unused, empty input?

Comment: Must the snippet be in the same language as the submission?

Comment: @boboquack very yes. It doesn't even need to be a programming language.

Comment: There should probably also be an exception for Unispace (https://esolangs.org/wiki/Unispace) (although there's no interpreter for it that I know of it)

Answer (score 7):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 20 snippets

```perl6
{$_ eq m/[[<-[()*?|\\]>|\\<[()*?|\\]>|'(' <~~>* ')']<[*?]>?|\|]+/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU5BjsIwDLzzCh9QG7ta0ILEYVWShyQVakoqIdEFyl7QBr7etY1Ae/BkbE/Gc07jcTMNNyh62E6/8x2kCwxL7@sPb5BcDqGxDPW/rjQl1I@HJSixbGpPrrG8yk21vE/X9gbzXVEs2LA/jXA8fKertYuf8TBMAG3sZoyOwaCwHImfoBAUhLYUnen2OYmm4vJcd/n0uVoHRJVn6VsTTZf3SAmp17nJAQl1Fzus6M3ESu7PmLhnEFmSmolKDzvNJzNlahTw5StSDZ7V132J8zM2/QE)

The snippets are taken from:

[`{$_ eq`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4066931/7957532), [`m/[`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112436/how-can-i-check-if-a-regex-pattern-is-valid-in-perl), [`<-[`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346101/replace-vs), [`()*?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/why-is-1-empty-in-my-substitution), [`|\\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354724/need-to-test-for-a-backslash-in-this-reg-ex), [`]>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620047/remove-trailing-from-the-page), [`|\\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354724/need-to-test-for-a-backslash-in-this-reg-ex), [`<[`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223556/infix-format-for-nemerle-macro), [`()*?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/344460/why-is-1-empty-in-my-substitution), [`|\\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/354724/need-to-test-for-a-backslash-in-this-reg-ex), [`]>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620047/remove-trailing-from-the-page), [`|`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/96667/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-java), [`'(' <~~>* ')'`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883506/7957532), [`<[`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/223556/infix-format-for-nemerle-macro), [`*?`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321299/what-is-the-reason-not-to-use-select), [`]>`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620047/remove-trailing-from-the-page), [`?|`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895304/how-to-add-r-n-in-a-varaible-in-sed), [`\|`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090491/perl-linux-command-not-working), [`]+/`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695338/using-regex-to-extract-information-from-a-file-and-need-help), [`}`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67894/why-do-we-need-extern-c-include-foo-h-in-c).

This is mostly the greedy approach (made obvious by all the one or two character snippets). I used [SymbolHound](http://symbolhound.com/advanced.php) to search for the individual characters, and the only real optimisation was the `'(' <~~>* ')'` snippet, which is taken from [my own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57883506/7957532) on recursive Perl 6 regexes.

#### Explanation:

This basically checks if the input is equal to a greedy match of a valid regex. The reason we can't just use the regex itself and add `^$` to mark the ends is because we are using a recursive regex, which wouldn't work if there were `^$` markers. The regex itself is:

```perl6
m/[                             ]+/   # Match one or more times
   [              ]  # Any of 
    <-[()*?|\\]> |     # Not a metacharacter
    \\<[()*?|\\]>      # A metacharacter preceded by a \
    '(' <~~>* ')'      # Brackets surrounding a valid regex
                   <[*?]>?  # Optionally followed by a ? or *
                           | \|    # Or just the | metacharacter
```

Comment: @guifa Yes, I learnt that through the [P6 specification](https://github.com/perl6/specs/blob/master/S05-regex.pod), which has a lot of things that haven't been properly documented yet. I suspect `~~` doesn't appear because it is not yet fully implemented (for example [`<~~0>`](https://github.com/perl6/specs/blob/master/S05-regex.pod)), though there are other hidden gems in there.